# Relation between harmonics and quantization

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, signal-synthesis, quantization, thd

I'd like to make digital samples that construct sine waves.
It's nothing but direct digital synthesis (DDS) before the digital-to-analog converter and filter.

I want to make a sinewave sample that swings between 1 and 10 (it could be any physical parameters such as voltage and current).

Look-up table determines almost accurate but not precise (due to quantization error) samples.

There could be two parameters

1. Resolution of the look-up table: how precisely can a single value be expressed?
2. Size of the look-up table : how many samples are between 1 and 10?

For example,
If I have a LUT with an integer value and 4 samples, I have sinewave samples like 1, 3, 8, 10.
But if I have 0.5 resolution and 8 samples, I can express it like 1, 1.5, 2.5, 4.5, 6.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.

So my question is:
How are size and resolution related to spurious contents (e.g., THD)?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/92011/output-spectrum-of-the-direct-digital-synthesis-dds

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because merging went "the wrong way".

Comment: Apologies for the rigamarole. I tried to merge the previous question onto this one, but the answers went to the closed question (the other one at the time was closed).  Let me know if I need to more to fix this.